# How do I make individually self-sizing UICollectionViewCells with multiple labels in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Here is my view controller:

```
//  ReadArticleViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Nathan Cain on 11/26/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Nathan Cain. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Realm

class ReadArticleViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    var pronunciationArray: [String] = []
    var wordArray: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var flow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

    var article: Article?

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pronunciationArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let wordCell: ReadArticleCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("wordCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ReadArticleCollectionViewCell
        println(pronunciationArray[indexPath.row])
        wordCell.pronunciationLabel.text = convertPinyinNumbersToToneMarks(pronunciationArray[indexPath.row])
        println(wordArray[indexPath.row])
        wordCell.wordLabel.text = wordArray[indexPath.row]
        println("wordCell width is \(wordCell.frame.size.width.description)")
        return wordCell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var Realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

        // tell the collection view layout object to let the cells self-size
        var flowLayout = self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 25, height: 50)

        println(article!.articleContent)
        let paragraphObjectsRLMArray = article!.paragraphs

        for (index,paragraphObject) in enumerate(paragraphObjectsRLMArray)
        {
            var paragraph = paragraphObject as Paragraph

            var sentenceObjectsRLMArray = paragraph.sentences

            for sentenceObject in sentenceObjectsRLMArray
            {
                let sentence = sentenceObject as Sentence
                let wordObjectsRLMArray = sentence.words

                for (index,word) in enumerate(wordObjectsRLMArray)
                {

                    let word = word as Word
                    let index = UInt(index)

                    wordArray.append(word.simplified)

                    print("word #\(index + 1) is \(word.simplified); ")

                    let pinyinArray = word.pinyin
                    let pinyinObject = definitionObject.pinyin as Pinyin?
                    if let pronunciationText: String? = Optional(convertPinyinNumbersToToneMarks(pinyinObject!.pinyin)) {
                        if pronunciationText != ""{
                            pronunciationArray.append(pinyinObject!.pinyin)//.text = pronunciationText!
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pronunciationArray.append(word.simplified)
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pronunciationArray.append("")
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Here is my collectionViewCell.swift

```
//
//  ReadArticleCollectionViewCell.swift
//
//  Created by Nathan Cain on 2/14/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Nathan Cain. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ReadArticleCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var pronunciationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!

}
```

When I run the app the cells don't adjust their sizes. Here is what it looks like with `-UIViewShowAlignmentRects YES` argument passed on launch:

[image: all cells the same width]

I would like each cell to be individually sized just wide enough to enclose its contents.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by modeling my view after what was done in this repository:
https://github.com/algal/SelfSizingCellsDemo

First you make a labelView and then add them to the subview (cell). Then you make a newLabel and size it and whatnot.

Next you set the autolayout constraints programmatically.

*Finally* you say self.labelView = newLabel

Comment: Thanks for showing me that repository. It does almost exactly what I want. I will try this and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Every collection view has an associated layout. You’re using the pre-made flow layout for this project.

Update the class declaration to indicate that it will conform to the flow layout delegate protocol:

```
class ReadArticleViewController: UIViewController, 
                                 UICollectionViewDelegate, 
                                 UICollectionViewDataSource,     
                                 UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Add the following methods:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!,
                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGSize {

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!,
                    insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

}
```

`collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` is responsible for telling the layout the size of a given cell. To do this, you must first determine which item you are looking at, since each item could have different dimensions.

`collectionView(_:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:)` returns the spacing between the cells, headers, and footers. A constant is used to store the value.

For much more information you can read the excellent [Beginning iOS Collection Views in Swift: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath`. Take a look at the project here for some ideas?
https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the delegate method on collectionViewLayout called sizeForItemAtIndexPath and return the correct size for each cell.